# Selecting next value in a list and not only returning the first when there are duplicates

Tags: java, selenium, ide, duplicates

i'm working with a list of invoice elements = type, with a corresponding sub-type, however since Selenium IDE only returns the first matched value, the sub-type is incorrect and I do not know how to move to the next Type value with the correct Sub-type value.

Say the list

```
Red Car, subtype = 1
Blue Car, subtype = 2
Yellow Car, subtype = 3
Red Car, subtype = 4
Blue Car, subtype = 5
```

I want to select the Red Car with sub-type = 4, However seleniumIDE automatically returns the first Red Car match and forgets about the others, but I want look through ALL of the Red Cars. This then crashes my test script as the sub-type for the returned Red Car sub-type is 1 and not 4.

```
 public void testQqqqqq() throws Exception {
    selenium.open("/invoicing/edit_car/-1?set_entityid=55184");
    selenium.click("css=div.content > div.buttonbar > button.primary");
    selenium.select("id=type", "label=Red Car");
    selenium.select("id=type", "label=Red Car");
```

as you can see, i've selected the first Red Car, and the second Red Car, but it just shows label=Red Car which always returns the first one even though its sub-type is wrong.

any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: show us your html, we cant do anything without it...

Comment: Can u please post the HTML Content of the page

Answer (score 0):

Instead of label just try with index. (If your options are always in same order)

Selenium.select("id=type", "index=4");